# Archiving email with camel (Talend)

Tags: java, apache-camel, pdfbox, talend

My requirement is, after reading email, I need to archive it as PDF (for the moment, let's consider plain text and excluding embedded texts from images).

Below is my code route that was generated from Talend-ESB (which I believe is the crux for explanation)

When I execute this, I get 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read while there is an open stream writer`

```
        from(
            "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993" + "?username=" + context.username
                    + "&password=" + decryptedPassword_cMail_1
                    + "&contentType=text/plain" + "&" + "peek" + "=true"
                    + "&" + "handleFailedMessage" + "=true" + "&"
                    + "skipFailedMessage" + "=true" + "&"
                    + "mapMailMessage" + "=true")

    .routeId("WriteAsPDF_cMail_1")
            .process(new org.apache.camel.Processor() {
                public void process(org.apache.camel.Exchange exchange)
                        throws Exception {
                    Map<String, Object> map = new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>();

                    map = exchange.getIn().getHeaders();
                    for (String name : map.keySet()) {
                        String key = name.toString();
                        String value = map.get(name).toString();
                        System.out.println(key + " " + value);

                    }
                    String M_Body = exchange.getIn().getBody().toString();
                    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument document = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument();

                    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage page = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage();

                    document.addPage(page);
                    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont pdfFont = org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
                    org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream contentStream = new org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream(
                            document, page);
                    contentStream.beginText();
                    contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, 12);
                    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);
                    contentStream.drawString(M_Body);
                    document.save("C:/Hari/poller/zipper/BlankPage.pdf");
                    contentStream.close();
                    document.close();
                }

            }).id("WriteAsPDF_cProcessor_1");
}
```

============================================

Exception details:

> [WARN ]: org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer - Exchange failed, so rolling back message status: Exchange[MailMessage@0xcdf6432]
>      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read while there is an open stream writer
>         at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createRawInputStream(COSStream.java:129)
>         at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromStream(COSWriter.java:1177)
>         at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.accept(COSStream.java:372)
>         at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObject(COSWriter.java:561)
>         at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObjects(COSWriter.java:490)
>      ...
>      .....
>      ..
>      ..
>      [ERROR]: org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-EINLW2ABC-60843-1468402879061-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-EINLW2ABC-60843-1468402879061-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot read while there is an open stream writer

I did check other questions similar to it, but I could not find things that would help me solve it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a screenshot of the Talend routine.

Comment: contentStream.close(); should have been done before saving. (don't know if that is the cause)

Comment: Hi @TilmanHausherr. Indeed it stopped the error. :) My code however needs to be rectified as PDF gets generated but only with a blank page. However, thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: The blank page is also because of the late closing (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391337/pdf-generated-with-pdfbox-is-blank ). If it still brings a blank page after that, then I'd suspect that "M_Body" is empty.

Comment: Hi @TilmanHausherr, based on your comment yesterday, I did perform contentStream.close() right after 

contentStream.drawString(M_Body);

After which, the exception was stopped, created PDF (but empty one) I also believe that M_Body to be empty. However, I shall check my code/logic again.

Comment: Any news on this? If you solved it, please delete the question. If not, I'd suggest you delete it too and create a new question.

Comment: I thought the comment of yours would help other members to who look up with similar problem to solve. Yes, the suggestion you gave helped me to fix. I am not aware of the rules of the forum, if you think that, deleting the question is good, then I shall do so.